# How to handle multiple queries of different HKQuantityTypeIdentifier

Tags: swift, model-view-controller, healthkit

I'm trying to get multiple types of health data all with the same timeframe. My problem relies on the way that I should handle all the data that I get from those queries. Currently my model is as follows:

```
struct DailyData {
    var steps: Int?
    var distance: Int?
    var calories: Int?
    var exercise: Int?
}

class UserData {
    let healthManager = HealthKitManager.shared
    var dailyData = [DailyData]?
    .
    .
    .
}
```

if I'm not mistaken, I can only query only one HKQuantityIdentifier at a time, so that means I need to call my `getData()` function from my `HealthKitManager.swift` once for every HKQuantityType that I have in my model:

```
func getData(type: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier, unit: HKUnit, days: Int, completed: @escaping (Result<[Int], Error>) -> Void) {
        let calendar = NSCalendar.current
        let interval = NSDateComponents()
        interval.day = 1
        
        let quantityType = HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: type)!
        
        var anchorComponents = calendar.dateComponents([.day, .month, .year], from: NSDate() as Date)
        anchorComponents.hour = 0
        let anchorDate = calendar.date(from: anchorComponents)
        
        // Define 1-day intervals starting from 0:00
        let query = HKStatisticsCollectionQuery(quantityType: quantityType,
                                                quantitySamplePredicate: nil,
                                                options: .cumulativeSum,
                                                anchorDate: anchorDate!,
                                                intervalComponents: interval as DateComponents)
        query.initialResultsHandler = {query, results, error in
            if let error = error {
                completed(.failure(error))
                return
            }
            
            let endDate = NSDate()
            let startDate = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: -(days - 1), to: endDate as Date, wrappingComponents: false)
            var completeDataArray: [Int] = []
            if let myResults = results{
                myResults.enumerateStatistics(from: startDate!, to: endDate as Date) { statistics, stop in
                    if let quantity = statistics.sumQuantity(){
                        let dayData = quantity.doubleValue(for: unit)
                        completeDataArray.append(Int(dayData))
                    }
                }
            }
            completed(.success(completeDataArray))
        }
        healthStore.execute(query)
    }
```

My problem is that I can't find a way to **correctly** set the received data into my model. Could someone point me in the right direction? I believe my model could be wrong, because as for what I have gather online, it's impossible to query multiple `HKQuantityTypes` in one query. Meaning that I would definitely have to set my model one `[Int]` of a `HKtype` at a time.

But with what I currently have, that would mean that when the first query returns I have to create multiple `DailyData` objects with almost all of the variables nil except the one I'm setting. Then, when the other queries return, I should do some array checking of `dailyData` matching the `.count` values with the one I got from the query, and that just feels wrong in my opinion. Not very elegant.

I tried another approach. Instead of having an array of a custom type, having a custom type that inside has an array of ints for every HKType that I need. But this has another problem: How could I "Keep in sync" the data from every HKType? having different arrays for every type would be, in my opinion, difficult to handle for example in a tableView. How could I set number of rows in section? Which type should I prefer? Also I would be accessing data over array indexes which may lead to bugs difficult to solve.

```
struct WeekData {
    var steps: [Int]?
    var distance: [Int]?
    var calories: [Int]?
    var exercise: [Int]?
}

class UserData {
    let healthManager = HealthKitManager.shared
    var weekData = WeekData()
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Comment: your first idea is correct. You have to match each subsequent data type to our first array based on date and then set the values in the entry for that date. You could use a dictionary with a key made of the date. Then you can find each entry quickly.